# I dont know how to get a datagridview Cell vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell

I have as final exam a project on the management of cinemas.
I'm now in the buying part of the movie place and it consists of me clicking on the cell of my datagridview(CellClick) and getting that value.
Do you have any idea how I can do it?
im doing vb.net

Datagridview:
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way... catch the cellclick event

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

This will throw a messagebox with the value of the cell clicked.